# How can globalizing 2 small arrays result in significant performance drop?

Tags: c, performance, motorola, 68000

I have 2 small local arrays:

```
short int xpLeft [4], xpRight [4];
```

The moment I make them **global** (to access them in different method, but only within same C file (e.g. not accessible to other modules)), the performance (on Motorola 68000) drops. 
Instead of 224 vblanks (for local), the whole benchmark (renders 320 frames of a scene) suddenly takes 249 vblanks (global array) !

What I tried:
Since the data in the arrays were not used in that function, I though that compiler caught that and did not bother with writing the resulting value (from register) to the memory (an extremely slow operation on 68000 - accessing the memory). So, I added some small code to use those array values at the end of the function, and it raised the performance cost accordingly (just 1 vblank).

What would help:
I need to examine the final ASM code (and compare both versions), but am unusure how to do that using **vbcc compiler** (from Dr. Volker). I tried few switches from the documentation, and while they did produce some intermediate output, I could not get it to provide a full ASM listing of each module (with the function names from C).

I just got the switch "-k" to work. Apparently, the order of the switches matters, and I found a place in the command line where it's recognized and I finally got the *.ASM output (with over 300 thousands lines no less), but I finally have something (ASM with symbols) to dig through.

What I think is happening:

1. making arrays global puts them into different address in RAM, and the memory controller has to access different bank, and the bank
   switch is an extremely slow operation on the target platform -
   resulting in RAS charge cycles (to access different row of
   addresses).
2. pointer aliasing - it's possible the compiler generates different code, and might actually access the actual memory for intermediate
       results - but if I had the ASM output for each function, I could
       figure that out easily

Any tips on why this is happening or how to get the vbcc output full listing of each compiled module with corresponding ASM code ?

With the ASM output I created a small test repro case:

```
short int tmpfn1 ()
{
    short int xpLeft [4], xpRight [4];
    short int i, tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        xpLeft [i] = 137 + i;
        xpRight [i] = 215 + i;
    }

    tmp = xpLeft [0] + xpRight [0];
    return tmp;
}
```

Here is the resulting ASM. While the ASM is pretty self-explanatory, I added few comments anyway:

```
    public  _tmpfn1
    cnop    0,4
_tmpfn1
    sub.w   #16,a7
    movem.l l4150,-(a7)
    moveq   #0,d1
    lea (0+l4152,a7),a1   ; a1 = &xpLeft [0]
    lea (8+l4152,a7),a2   ; a2 = &xpRight [0]
    move.w  #215,d3    ; d2/d3 = The Bulgarian constants 
    move.w  #137,d2
l4148
    move.w  d1,d0
    ext.l   d0
    lsl.l   #1,d0
    move.w  d2,(0,a1,d0.l)    ; xpLeft [i] = 137 + i;
    move.w  d3,(0,a2,d0.l)    ; xpRight [i] = 215 + i;
    addq.w  #1,d1    ; d1 = Loop Counter (i++)
    addq.w  #1,d2
    addq.w  #1,d3
    cmp.w   #4,d1
    blt l4148    ; Repeat the loop
    move.w  (8+l4152,a7),d0
    add.w   (0+l4152,a7),d0    ; tmp = xpLeft [0] + xpRight [0];
l4150   reg a2/d2/d3
    movem.l (a7)+,a2/d2/d3
    add.w   #16,a7
l4152   equ 12
    rts
; stacksize=28
    opt 0
    opt NQLPSMRBT
```

Now, I will go place the arrays from local to global.

Here is the code with global variables.

```
    public  _tmpfn1
    cnop    0,4
_tmpfn1
    movem.l l4150,-(a7)
    moveq   #0,d1
    move.w  #215,d2
    move.w  #137,d3
l4148
    move.w  d1,d0
    ext.l   d0
    lsl.l   #1,d0
    lea _AxpLeft,a0
    move.w  d3,(0,a0,d0.l)
    lea _AxpRight,a0
    move.w  d2,(0,a0,d0.l)
    addq.w  #1,d1
    addq.w  #1,d3
    addq.w  #1,d2
    cmp.w   #4,d1
    blt l4148
    move.w  _AxpRight,d0
    add.w   _AxpLeft,d0
l4150   reg d2/d3
    movem.l (a7)+,d2/d3
l4152   equ 8
    rts
; stacksize=8
    opt 0
    opt NQLPSMRBT
```

The only difference is the two lea instructions which, if memory serves right, is max 16 cycles.
There must be something else happening with the actual function, but for some reason, its code is obfuscated in the ASM (there's just 6 lines in ASM, no jumps, no other labels, nothing). I'll keep searching the ASM, where exactly the code is.

Comment: The code obviously switches to a different addressing mode. (from SP-relative to absolute)

Comment: Yes, but the stack (on the platform) is put at the end of RAM, meaning every single access to the stack variables results in those expensive RAS cycles (unless your code happens to result at that last RAM page - which it doesn't, as it resides at the start of RAM). While I'm not sure what is the difference in cycles between those 2 addressing modes, (I can look it up), I doubt it can amount for that kind of a performance drop.

Comment: [I don't know 68K instruction timing / addressing modes] at least the instruction sequence (+decoding) can be shorter for SP-relative addressing.

Comment: I just looked it up at the cycle table, and move.w takes between 16(best)-24 (worst) cycles. Since that method is executed only 320*3 = 960 times, the difference should be, at worst, 960*(24-16) = 7,680 cycles. But it's ~3-4 orders of magnitude more than that !

Comment: This can't be explained by the RAS precharge cycles either. The compiler must be doing something brutal. I'm pretty sure sure if I saw the resulting ASM code, it would be a monster-WTF moment. I'm going to retry those compiler switches again, maybe try few different optimization options in the compiler.

Comment: BTW: the indexing could be different too for different addressing modes.

Comment: true, but from cycles perspective, as I computed above, we're talking max. 8,000 cycles of a difference. And even if previously the arrays would be just stored in registers (e.g. compiler noticed they weren't touched by the code below, so it never bothered to write the result to the actual memory address - which is a huge if), that would just double the cycle count difference to 16-20,000 (as move.w with registers still takes at least 12 cycles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, there is a monster-WTF compiler-related moment. The reason, why there were just 6 lines of code in case of local variables, is that the compiler was able to figure out, that those 120 lines of C code are not really doing anything on a global level, so it completely ignored the code altogether ! Meaning the ASM code for the method was just those 6 lines (with rts). That however does not make much sense with the benchmark results I got (but that will be a different story)

Moral of the story : By Making the variable global, the compiler actually bothered to create the code for the function (and not just empty 6-op stub). And since I inlined everything inside that function, there were no nested function calls.
Now, this obviously sounds ridiculous, given I had about 25 debugging sessions with the variables and output on a target device. But the moment, I removed those external print/debugging calls, that must have been the moment the compiler didn't produce the function code at all. A-bloody-mazing....